# Multiple Drop Downs in Navigation Bar Overlapping each other in a HTML page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement two drop down items in a html page. But the problem is they are not position right at the bottom of there drop down text, but they are overlapping each other. Try margin property, but I want to position them automatically. I made the style sheet code so that i could use to universely use it, wherever I like, and to show the drop content, just I have to add hover event in the drop down

for the dropdown content, which will position it to absolute with block display.

The CSS Code is:

```css
.NavBar{
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #616161;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.NavBarList{
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #616161;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
}
.NavBarList:hover{
    background-color: black;
}
.content{
    display: none;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.content a{
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    min-width: 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
.content a:hover{
    background-color: #81D4FA;
}
.content a:hover .NavBarList{
    background-color: black;
}


The HTML Code is:
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
 <link href="NavBar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <style>
     #Home:hover #homeContent{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
     }
     #AboutUs:hover #AboutUsContent{
  display: block;
  position: absolute; 
     }
 </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#1976D2" >
 <ul class="NavBar">
     <li class="NavBarList" id="Home">
  Home
  <div class="content" id="homeContent">
      <a href="#">Bus</a>
      <a href="#">Route</a>
      <a href="#">Bus and Route</a>
  </div>
     </li>
     <li class="NavBarList" id="AboutUs">
  About Us
  <div class="content" id="AboutUsContent">
      <a href="#">Bus1</a>
      <a href="#">Route1</a>
      <a href="#">Bus and Route1</a>
  </div>
     </li>
 </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position: relative` on `.NavBarList` and `left: 0` on `.content`, like:

```
.NavBarList {
    position: relative;
}
.content {
    left: 0;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.NavBar{
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #616161;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.NavBarList{
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #616161;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
}
.NavBarList:hover{
    background-color: black;
}
.content{
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.content a{
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    min-width: 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
.content a:hover{
    background-color: #81D4FA;
}
.content a:hover .NavBarList{
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
 <link href="NavBar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <style>
     #Home:hover #homeContent{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
     }
     #AboutUs:hover #AboutUsContent{
  display: block;
  position: absolute; 
     }
 </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#1976D2" >
 <ul class="NavBar">
     <li class="NavBarList" id="Home">
  Home
  <div class="content" id="homeContent">
      <a href="#">Bus</a>
      <a href="#">Route</a>
      <a href="#">Bus and Route</a>
  </div>
     </li>
     <li class="NavBarList" id="AboutUs">
  About Us
  <div class="content" id="AboutUsContent">
      <a href="#">Bus1</a>
      <a href="#">Route1</a>
      <a href="#">Bus and Route1</a>
  </div>
     </li>
 </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS Position References: [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/), [Codeacademy](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-6merh/3/1)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, but now the nav bar has a margin of 5px in the left.

Comment: my nav bar needs to be always fixed at the top of the page.

Comment: @MananTrimbakey Ya its fixed. Whats the issue then?

Comment: can you tell me more about display and position property... I am not able to understand fully... provide a link a if you can

Comment: @MananTrimbakey Have a look at these links for reference: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/ , https://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-6merh/3/1

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I think you mean that you want each dropdown menu to appear below its parent navbar element, as opposed to all dropdowns being shifted all the way to the left.  If that's indeed what you mean, I tried changing the `display` property of the `.NavBarList` class from `inline` to `inline-block`, and that seemed to help (see screenshot above).  The code for this change can be found @ this JSFiddle link here:

http://jsfiddle.net/1gk98gmw/

You can further adjust the grey space between the parent navbar elements and the grey navbar itself by removing the `padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px` from the `.NavBar` class:

[image]

Comment: i figured out for the deposition-ing of the content, setting different z-index helps.

Comment: Hmmm `z-index` just changes the stack order of DOM elements that may otherwise overlap with each other, i.e. it determines which element will be placed above which other element(s).  Not sure how that could affect the relative horizontal placement of the submenus.

W3 Schools has a good, short tutorial on hoverable mavbar submenus, link here- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning positions an element to it's closest **positioned** ancestor - as none of the element's ancestors have a set `position` then the element defaults to the position of the window. You need to set the position of the absolute element's parent, as well as give it a set left value, as below:

```
.NavBarList {
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks its working but now the nav bar has a margin of 5px from left.

Comment: Do you mean the entire bar? There's no reason for that to happen from that code

Comment: my nav bar needs to be always fixed at the top of the page

Comment: I am not able to send u the image.

Comment: but it has a margin of some pixels now